# React Typescript: Reflection (listing properties of an interface)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, reflection, abstract-syntax-tree, react-typescript

im writing a node-based editor for neural-nets that (currently) uses tensorflow.js for the creation of the networks themself. Tensorflow.js has a layers api with diffrent factory-functions that each have an interface for their arguments. E.g.

```js
interface DenseLayerArgs {
    units: number, 
    useBias?: boolean, 
    ...
}
const dense(args: DenseLayerArgs): {
...
}
```

My goal is to load all of those factory functions automaticly and create a menu for each thats based on the Args interface. Since its not possible to access properties that might be undefined in plain TS, the solution seems to be some kind of transformer library (eg. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-reflection ). But i havnt been able to get any custom transformer running with my create-react-app with typescript setup.

Has anyone been able to get React working with custom transformers or has some other solution for creating a menu from an interface ?

cheers

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the [tst-reflect](https://github.com/Hookyns/ts-reflection) for the TypeScript Reflection.

In the README, there is a section [How to Start](https://github.com/Hookyns/ts-reflection#how-to-start). You have to use eg. `ttypescript` to get transformers working. TypeScript does not support transformers out of the box, only by direct calls to their Compiler API. `ttypescript` is some kind of wrap which allows you to define transformers in tsconfig.

**Copy of that How to Start:**

1. Install packages.

```
npm i tst-reflect && npm i tst-reflect-transformer -D
```

2. In order to use transformer plugin you need TypeScript compiler which supports plugins eg. package [ttypescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ttypescript) or you can use [TypeScript compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) manually.

```
npm i ttypescript -D
```

3. Add transformer to `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // your options...

        // ADD THIS!
        "plugins": [
            {
                "transform": "tst-reflect-transformer"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

4. Now just transpile your code by `ttsc` instead of `tsc`

```
npx ttsc
```

**And usage with Webpack:**

Modify your webpack config. Use `options.compiler` of `ts-loader` to set `ttypescript` compiler.

```js
({
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
    loader: require.resolve("ts-loader"),
    options: {
        compiler: "ttypescript"
    }
})
```

**And how to list the properties of an Interface with `tst-reflect`?**

```js
import { getType, Property} from "tst-reflect";

interface DenseLayerArgs {
    units: number, 
    useBias?: boolean, 
    // ...
}

const properties: Array<Property> = getType<DenseLayerArgs>().getProperties();
// Do something with properties...
```

`Property` is:

```js
interface Property
{
    /**
     * Property name
     */
    readonly name: string;
    /**
     * Property type
     */
    readonly type: Type;
    /**
     * Optional property
     */
    readonly optional: boolean;
    /**
     * Access modifier
     */
    readonly accessModifier: AccessModifier;
    /**
     * Accessor
     */
    readonly accessor: Accessor;
    /**
     * Readonly
     */
    readonly readonly: boolean;
    /**
     * Returns array of decorators
     */
    getDecorators(): ReadonlyArray<Decorator>;
}
```